# How can I tell when the last time Chrome updated?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I would like to be able to tell when the last time my version of Google Chrome updated. I would also like to be able to tell what version I had before my last update.

Ideally a log of every update my version of Chrome has made with dates and versions would be the best.

I am trying to troubleshoot a bug that just got introduced in Chrome and I think it is related to a chrome update.

Comment: You didn't mention what operating system.

Comment: How about ubuntu?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In OS X, open a Terminal and enter:

```
ls -l "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions"
```

This will print the current version and the previous one (including its installation date):

```
drwxrwxr-x  11 werner  admin  352 Aug 24 01:13 76.0.3809.132
drwxrwxr-x  11 werner  admin  352 Sep 18 01:03 77.0.3865.90
lrwxrwxr-x   1 werner  admin   12 Sep 18 01:03 Current -> 77.0.3865.90
```

Comment: This no longer works

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Updated with a working solution.

Answer (score 19):

If you're using Windows 7 or Vista (maybe XP, but don't have it handy to test) Chrome actually installs to *AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application* which will contain the previous version and the current version along with sub-directories named after the version number.

The directory names and date information hold the information you asked for.

Update: Chrome often installs under Program Files now so the new location to check would be: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, however I forgot to mention I am on a Mac (Lion).

Comment: An update to the update: Chrome now has a 64-bit build, so you'd find that at `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`.